# How do I include escape sequences in a string variable

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I have a type with a string property called 'TestValue' that contains a string that includes characters that are escape sequences for c#. e.g. "blah\"". I need these characters to print out to the console as well.

`Console.WriteLine(obj.TestValue);` // prints only **blah"**

When I hover over that variable in the debugger I can see the exact string "blah\"", but when printed out to the console, only **blah"** shows up, I want **blah\"** to show up.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I find it interesting that no one has answered this question as asked.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(obj.TestValue.Replace("\"", "\\\"").Replace("\n", "\\n"));` etc.

Is this a possibility? You may put it in an extension method and include any escape sequence to your likings.

Answer (score 3):

Choose one: `@"blah\"""` or `"blah\\\""`

`@` denotes a verbatim string, but you still need to escape a double quote by doubling it up. Or you can simply escape the `\` by doubling it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find in [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) the escape sequences which include Backslash and Double quotation mark. So, you have to escape them both by a backslash like the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Blah\\\"");
```

Comment: I know about '@', the problem in my case is that all i have access to is "obj.TestValue". Not the actual string. I only have the variable.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use \ to escape any characters. so, if you want to print the \ character, use `\\`

Comment: I know about '@', the problem in my case is that all i have access to is "obj.TestValue". Not the actual string. I only have the variable. – Cranialsurge